# Extend Existing CSS style by percent- % using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to extend an existing css style by 1%, using the following code, but instead its being increment in pixels instead of %.So instead of giving - `7%`, its giving me it as `7px`.

```
$("#label").css("top", "+=1%");
```

The top most div is of size - `width: 100%;` and the *label*  `top : 6%` which is already defined.

Any idea/suggestion on this would be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to get the current top property value, and then add 1%;

```
var currentTop = $("#label").css("top");
var topAdded = parseInt(currentTop.replace("%","")) + 1;
$("#label").css("top", topAdded + "%");
```

Comment: Thanks @jmartins for solution. It works, but wondering if we can implement it in a single statement

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var top = parseInt($("#label").css("top").replace("%", ""));
top ++; 
$("#label").css("top", top+"%")
```

**Update:**

For one line statement you can do this:

```
 $("#label").css("top", (parseInt($("#label").css("top").replace("%", "")+1)+"%")
```

Comment: Thanks @hamed for the reponse. It works, but wondering if we can implement it in a single statement

Comment: Thanks Hamed, since @jmartins has provided solution first, accepting his answer.

Comment: Corrected your response-

$("#label").css("top", (parseInt($("#label").css("top").replace("%", ""))+1+"%"))